# If God doesn't tempt us, why does the Lord's Prayer petition Him to "lead us not into temptation"?

Tags: gospel-of-matthew, textual-discrepancies, temptation, lords-prayer, book-of-james

[Matthew 6:9-13](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew%206) Jesus instructs us:

> “This, then, is how you should pray:
>
> “‘Our Father in heaven,
> hallowed be your name,
> your kingdom come,
> your will be done,
> on earth as it is in heaven.
> Give us today our daily bread.
> And forgive us our debts,
> as we also have forgiven our debtors.
> **And lead us not into temptation**,
> but deliver us from the evil one.’"

But [James 1:13-14](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=James%201) says:

> When tempted, no one should say, “God is tempting me.” For God cannot be tempted by evil, **nor does he tempt anyone**; but each person is tempted when they are dragged away by their own evil desire and enticed.

If God doesn't tempt us, why does the Lord's Prayer petition Him not to lead us into temptation?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The phrase is part of a couplet, so it needs to be read in that context.

> Lead us not into temptation,
>   but deliver us from evil.

The phrase does not assume that God *might* lead us into temptation. Instead, it assumes that God does deliver us from evil. The couplet gives the impression that temptations *will* come, but prays that God delivers us from them. The [New Living Translation](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew%206&version=NLT) attempts to make this more clear:

> And don’t let us yield to temptation,
>   but rescue us from the evil one.

Through other Scriptures, we know that God does not tempt anyone ([James 1:13](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=James%201)), and we also know that God will always have a way out when temptation comes ([1 Corinthians 10:13](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Corinthians%2013)). A proper systematic theology will look at all the Scriptures that mention a subject to help interpret the more difficult or confusing passages. In this case, other Scriptures make this clear, that God does not tempt and does deliver us from temptation. This is exactly what the prayer asks: when temptation does come (because it will), God save us from it.

Comment: Alternatively, one could read it "lead us; not into temptation, but [so as to] deliver us from evil". Not disagreeing with your answer, just offering an alternate grammatical take that arrives at the same place.

Answer (score 4):

This may be a simplistic answer, but it came as something of an "aha!" moment to me when I first heard it many years ago:

In general, it is probably not the best idea to ask God to do something God doesn't want to do, or to ask God *not* to do something God *does* want to do.

Presumably God's will and God's knowledge of the situation is better than ours. So if we were (theoretically) to succeed in getting God to change God's mind, it would always be for the worse, not for the better.

If, on the other hand, we ask God to do things God already *does* want to do, and ask God *not* to do things God already *does not* want to do, then we're asking things that are in harmony with God's will and God's knowledge, which is better than ours.

So in asking God *not to lead us into temptation,* which is something God already doesn't want to do, we are praying for something that is according to God's will.

*Short version:* The purpose of prayer is not to get God to change God's mind. Instead, it is to prompt change in our own mind (and heart) so that we are more in harmony with God's mind (and heart).

A prayer for God not to lead us into temptation is really a request for God to help us not to get *ourselves* into temptation by thinking, wanting, and doing foolish and evil things.

Comment: About as "simplistic" as an M. C. Escher drawing. :-) Thank you for answering. What came to mind though were instances where someone does get God to change His mind, e.g., the Syrophoenician woman in Mark 7.

Comment: @rainbow Haha! Well, maybe I could have stated it a little more clearly. About the Syrophonoecian woman, I've always read it as Jesus testing her rather than as Jesus changing his mind. But I know it's often interpreted as Jesus changing his mind.

Comment: It does seem that the whole prayer is about things God has already done. His name is already hallowed, His kingdom will come, His will is always done, if you're praying to Him He has already forgiven you, He doesn't tempt you, and He has already delivered you from evil. The only questionable grace is daily bread, which I've added as another question: Can Daily Bread refer to Jesus Christ? In which case, He is already with us daily. So all the petitions are just meditations on what God has already done, and then, agreed, harmonizing yourself to His mind and heart.

Comment: Seems your theory works for every line : He has told us He is in Heaven, and hallowed. He has promised His kingdom will come, His will will be done, and has promised daily Bread of Life to the regenerate, and to forgive us as we forgive, to never lead us into temptation, to deliver us if we call on Him in Christ’s name. etc. (i left out the lead line this comment first time ‍♂️)

Answer (score 2):

Cf. ARTICLE 3 THE SEVEN PETITIONS > VI. "AND LEAD US NOT INTO TEMPTATION" > [**CCC 2846**](http://www.vatican.va/archive/ccc_css/archive/catechism/p4s2a3.htm#2846)

CCC 2846 explains that the Greek means both *"do not allow us to enter into temptation"* and *"do not let us yield to temptation."*

> **CCC 2846** This petition goes to the root of the preceding one, for our sins result from our consenting to temptation; we therefore ask
>   our Father not to "lead" us into temptation. It is difficult to
>   translate the Greek verb used by a single English word: **the Greek
>   means both "do not allow us to enter into temptation" and "do not let
>   us yield to temptation."**<sup>1</sup> "God cannot be tempted by evil
>   and he himself tempts no one";<sup>2</sup> on the contrary, he wants
>   to set us free from evil. We ask him not to allow us to take the way
>   that leads to sin. We are engaged in the battle "between flesh and
>   spirit"; this petition implores the Spirit of discernment and
>   strength.

<sup>1 *Cf. Mt 26:41.*</sup>
<sup>2 *Jas 1:13.*</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Here's my take:

First, the Greek can mean test or it can mean tempt or it can mean try (trial).

Now, let's look at other scriptures for context:

- Jesus was led by God (Spirit) into the wilderness to be tested/tempted (Mt 4:1). God led him into the trial, where Satan did the tempting.
- God does not tempt anyone (James 1:13). But He does test/try us (Asked Abraham to sacrifice his son) (Heb 11:17).
- Jesus tells us to pray to **not** enter or fall into temptation (Mt 26:41,Luke 22:46)
- We should count it all joy when faced with trials/tests because they develop perseverance (James 1:2)

Putting all this together, here's my conclusion:

If God tests us (but not tempts us), the Lord's prayer is asking...

"lead me not into a place of **testing** *that exposes me to the evil one*, but *rather* deliver me from the evil one". (note this gives the idea of a couplet)

Another source used this comparison: God is a trainer leading us into an arena to fight, and Satan is the opponent. It's OK to ask God not to lead us there. And it's OK to not want to go through severe testing (even Jesus asked to avoid the cross if possible, but accepted God's will (Mark 14:36)).

Finally, it's OK for God to lead me to a place of testing that exposes my sin (which is in me, and provides Satan a foothold). This testing can develop perseverance. I'm supposed to "count it all joy" for this kind of training/testing.

Comment: Good answer.  [Leon Morris's commentary](https://www.logos.com/product/3443/the-gospel-according-to-matthew) and [R.T. France](https://www.amazon.com/dp/B003ISJBT2/) also highlight how "testing" may be the right meaning here, and both link to Jas 1:13.  R.T. France also links it to Matt 4:1.  Morris mentions [Good News Bible translation](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew%206%3A13&version=GNT) which uses "testing".

Answer (score 0):

It’s not just the temptation line, *Every* line in the Lord’s Prayer is a Biblical promise, something that God has declared is true or promised that He will do.

He has told us He is in Heaven, and hallowed. He has promised His kingdom will come, His will will be done, and has promised daily Bread of Life to the regenerate, and to forgive us as we forgive, to deliver us if we call on Him in Christ’s name. etc