# Is this the original Lord's Prayer?

Tags: prayer

Why nowadays the Christians say in prayer:

"**Our Father** who art in heaven, ...

**LEAD US NOT into TEMPTATION**, ..."

Is their Father the ”TEMPTER / Deceiver” ???

Are those words the original words Christ thought us ???

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If God doesn't tempt us, why does the Lord's Prayer petition Him to "lead us not into temptation"?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/39858/if-god-doesnt-tempt-us-why-does-the-lords-prayer-petition-him-to-lead-us-not)

Answer (score 2):

The [original text](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew%206%3A9-13&version=ESV;SBLGNT) is

> καὶ μὴ εἰσενέγκῃς ἡμᾶς εἰς πειρασμόν (Matthew  6:13).

which translates literally as

> And do not lead us into a trial.

The key word is πειρασμός, which, according to [Strong’s Greek concordance](http://biblehub.com/greek/3986.htm), can mean **an experiment, a trial,** or **temptation.** (It is derived from [πειράζω](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=peira%2Fzw&la=greek&can=peira%2Fzw0#lexicon), which means essentially “to test.”)

It is not necessary to interpret this petition as implying that the Father is the tempter (as if the Father, like the Devil, attempts to provoke us to sin).

The petition can be interpreted, rather, in two complementary ways:

1. Especially if we interpret πειρασμός as “temptation to sin,” we should observe that it is possible (and probably preferable), in Matthew’s Semitic Greek, to read “do not lead us into temptation” as “lead us away from temptation.” In that case, it is clear that the Father is not the Tempter, but the one who *protects* us from temptation. (Although He might, in His infinite wisdom, permit temptation at times, He is not its *cause*.)
2. The πειρασμός might mean mean “trial,” which is broader than “temptation”—it can include all the sufferings that we might encounter. In that case, the “trial” might be something permitted by the Father in order for us to grow in love and virtue. In any case, Jesus instructs us to ask the Father to be lenient!

Comment: Why is it preferable to read "do not lead us into temptation"  as "lead us away from temptation"? You're suggesting that this is a Semitism? (Also, I know this isn't Hermeneutics.SE, but it remains true that [Strong's is a concordance, not a lexicon](http://meta.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/923/3555). See LSJ [πειράζω](http://stephanus.tlg.uci.edu/lsj/#eid=82804&context=lsj&action=hw-list-click) (the verb) and, since you've brought up the Semitic background, BDB [נסה](https://archive.org/stream/hebrewenglishlex00browuoft#page/650/mode/1up).)

Comment: @Susan Regarding the concordance, fair enough, although various [lexicons](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=peira%2Fzw&la=greek&can=peira%2Fzw0) give the same meaning. Regarding the interpretation, Biblical language commonly attributes to God something that He merely allows, as if He were its instigator (e.g., when God “hardens the Pharaoh’s heart,” when it is evident from the context that Pharaoh hardens his _own_ heart; see Ex. 9:12). Since Jesus makes it clear in other places that the Devil, not God, is the Deceiver (see, e.g., Jn. 8:14), it follows that this passage is similar.

Comment: @Susan Frankly, we just don't talk like that anymore.  However it was perfectly understood at the time it was transliterated / translated.  At this point, we're just splitting hairs in regards to the words used.